# Stopping HTML5 video hls stream in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, stream, html5-video

On the web, I have a video which fetches .m3u8 playlist natively using video's src attribute. Video starts playing, everything is fine.

Before playing video, I am adding an eventListener to video:

```
video.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e)
})
```

Then, in some moment, I want to stop the video, so I do:

```
video.pause()
video.setAttribute('src', '')
```

This throws an error in Safari. In other browsers, it works nicely. I am setting src to empty string, because I do not want to fetch segments in background.

I also tried `video.removeAttribute('src')` or `video.src = ''`, everytime ending up with an error.

So the question is, **how to stop HTML5 video hls stream in Safari without getting an error**?

Comment: what's the error? I usually `pause()` and set `currentTime=0` if the user won't be continuing the video. If I really want to tidy up, I'll remove the element from the DOM and replace with an image placeholder

Comment: @Offbeatmammal it's MediaError - unsupported source type

Comment: it's right ... no source file is an unsupported type ;) would suggest trapping and ignoring the error (set currentTime to zero might avoid the need to clear the source though)

Comment: Yes, it is and I understand. Thats why I am asking this question about stopping it. When I do video.pause() and set currentTime to 0, video still fetches playlist in the background, which is not what I want.